# 12.04 to 12.10 thunderbird vs evolution

Tags: thunderbird, evolution, dist-upgrade

If I upgrade from 12.04 to 12.10 what happens to my evolution? Will I have to use Thunderbird or will I have a choice?

Answer (score 1):

Thunderbird id the default mail client even in 12.04. Upgrading won't remove Evolution.

In any case it is recommended you backup your data before upgrading. You might encounter problems during such a major operation as an OS upgrade.